# MySQL aliased subquery cannot be used in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query given below that returns all the data asked. Then in the next query I need to write I need to restrict the output to where the subquery is greater than 5.

I will show examples but I cannot understand why I cannot do what I am attempting.

Query without restriction

```
select t1.BOOK_NUM, t1.BOOK_TITLE,
(select count(t2.CHECK_OUT_DATE) 
from checkout t2
where t2.BOOK_NUM = t1.BOOK_NUM) as Times_Checked_Out
from book t1
order by Times_Checked_Out desc, t1.BOOK_TITLE;
```

Screenshot of output
[image]

Attempt at query with restrictions

```
select t1.BOOK_NUM, t1.BOOK_TITLE,
(select count(t2.CHECK_OUT_DATE) 
from checkout t2
where t2.BOOK_NUM = t1.BOOK_NUM) as Times_Checked_Out
from book t1
where Times_Checked_Out > 5
order by Times_Checked_Out desc, t1.BOOK_TITLE;
```

Error
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a derived column in a where clause, need to use `HAVING`:

```
select t1.BOOK_NUM, t1.BOOK_TITLE,
(select count(t2.CHECK_OUT_DATE) 
from checkout t2
where t2.BOOK_NUM = t1.BOOK_NUM) as Times_Checked_Out
from book t1
HAVING Times_Checked_Out > 5
order by Times_Checked_Out desc, t1.BOOK_TITLE;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, when the time is up I will mark as the answer.

Comment: Can you also help me understand this, I have the output in the screenshot but instead of the column heading being Times_Checked_Out I want Times Checked Out but when I use 'text' I don't get any results.